# Looking for a better way to hide search bar at top of view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have several views where I want the search bar to be hidden unless the user scrolls it down to use it.  I use this command to achieve this:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 44) animated:NO];
```

This works ok, but it's not ideal;  any time something happens that causes the table view to reload, it has to be repositioned again.

Now I have a view where I want to completely hide the search bar from the user, meaning they can't even scroll down to get to it, *but* I want to keep the scope bars at the top of the table.  So basically I want to scroll the search bar off the top of the view and keep it there, while leaving the scope bar portion of the control visible.  setContentOffset isn't doing it for me anymore, since the user can easily undo it.

Is there an approach to this that I'm overlooking?

Thanks in advance!

Update:  I never figured this out, so ultimately I changed my design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's probably a bit late, when you say "any time something happens that causes the table view to reload, it has to be repositioned again", are you saying that every time your `UITableView` reloads it scrolls to its top? This isn't the standard behaviour of a `UITableView`.

In regards to the second part of your question regarding your `UISearchBar`'s scope, I'd strongly recommend replacing the `UISearchBar` with your own `UISegmentedControl` (that's all the scope of a `UISearchBar` is anyway), so that the user isn't confused by there being an off-screen `UISearchBar` that doesn't do anything.

Comment: No, the table doesn't reposition to the top. I'm just testing with relatively small amounts of data, so it all fits on one screen.  Good point on the UISegmentedControl;  if I decide to go back to this design I'll definitely use that.